# Stored procedure joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, integration

I have just added a temporary table to my stored procedure and I am trying to join this table to other fields in this stored procedure. This change affects the way my package will run. So the procedure runs ok but my package gives me an error 'to remove external columns' example

```
If object_id() is null
Begin
Create table #...
Insert into table #...
(
Value int
Name varchar
)

Select value from # where .....

End
```

This runs fine but I think my problem comes from the join as below

```
Select ab.value, * from
(

Select top 100
...
...
...
...

Case when this then this 
Else null
End as usage

From ...
Left join ...
On 
Left join..
On
Left join
On 

)cd

Left join #.. ab on
ab. =  cd.
```

The result of this joins my original stored procedure (ie the cd table in bracket)to the temporary table created and brings back null fields. It isn't what I want. A right join doesn't work either. Can I add this as a case statement?

I only want the 'value' field from the temporary table as a field in my result. And I want to be able to map this in my ssis package.

Comment: if your Outer Join is returning all nulls for table ab, then its not finding matching records.  Are you sure what that the column you are matching on is the same in AB and CD?

Comment: They are not the same. I only want to return the field 'value' from the temp table in addition to the other fields.

Comment: Then I'm assuming the temp table has a single row?  Then you might want to look at a regular variable instead of a temp table.  You need to remove the connection part of your join, and then it will return the row in AB for every one in CD.  HOWEVER, cartesian product queries are REALLY bad practice, they eat process time.

Comment: Please can you explain further...? To remove the left join and create a regular variable instead of a temp table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should be done if your temp table has a single row

```
declare @whatever varchar(10);
set @whatever = 'Foo'

select @whatever, A.* from table_A as A
```

If your temp table has more than one row, you are doing a Cartesian product (it matches every row in table A to ALL the rows in table B.  THIS IS A VERY BAD THING TO DO!

```
Select * from table_A, table_B  (make no comparison statement)
```

if you do this, it will kill your system.  As an example, I did this to with two small tables (439, and 193 rows)  my result set was over 47,000 records! This is bad, bad, bad.

Did I mention this is a horrible thing to do?

Comment: Thank you. I hard coded the data using a case statement  in the original stored procedure (. I removed the temp table and the join) and it worked fine.